# DFT algorithm designed for a "sample-by-sample" senario

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, algorithms, terminology

Suppose I have a system that wants to take an input signal (audio in this case) and wants to output a Discrete Fourier Transform of it in real time (ie every sample).

My initial thought is that if you are just every sample adding a new sample and bumping off a the oldest sample you could reuse the some of the computation from the last sample.

After googling around I wasn't able to find anything like that on the web.

So my question is this:

Does an algorithm like this exist and what is it called?

Comment: Search for "streaming DFT" or "online DFT".

Comment: @MBaz Thanks....this appears to be what I was looking for

Comment: ...which only leaves us with the question of how to close this question gracefully (?). Maybe @MBaz can provide an answer and DarthRubik accept it? Or if DarthRubik now thinks the question could be deleted (?) You can always comes back about clarification ofcourse.

Comment: @RickLyons (don't know whether that works to summon him) done an IEEE "DSP tricks" article on the "sliding DFT", I sadly can't find it right now, that's what I think you need.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think this is it: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1184347

Comment: I've heard this algorithm is called a "sliding DFT".  You may have to untwist the incremental phase rotation, depending on you requirements (if any) for a phase zero reference point.

Comment: @MBaz indeed! But I think there was a freely accessible version floating around at a reputable source. Hm.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Google Scholar is good for finding freely available versions... it finds a few copies of this particular paper.